# Kotlin Multiplatform using experimental @ObjCName in Android Studio on Windows

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform

I'm starting to use KMM to share business logic between Android and iOS. I create the shared Kotlin code in Android Studio on Windows, and get this across to Mac OS for use in XCode.

On Mac OS I can use these experimental annotations to set the Swift name for a class:

```
import kotlin.experimental.ExperimentalObjCName
import kotlin.native.ObjCName

@OptIn(ExperimentalObjCName::class)
@ObjCName(swiftName = "UtilResourceDelegate")
```

However these are not compiling in AS on Windows. They should just be ignored of course, as ObjC isn't present, but they are instead resulting in a fatal compile error.

Is there a way of AS on Windows accepting (and ignoring) these, so that I can share the source between there and Mac OS?

Edit to add further info:

```
Android Studio on Windows (from build.grade) - org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.7.21

KMM Plugin (from Settings | Plugins - JetBrains 0.5.3(221)-13
```

This is Android Studio on Windows, so it doesn't have multiple source sets. This is just the code used for my Android build, which is done on Windows. It's shared code, but just in the usual src | main | java | com.xxxx folder.

The IDE highlights the above import statements with errors:

```
import kotlin.experimental.ExperimentalObjCName [Unresolved reference ExperimentalObjCName]
import kotlin.native.ObjCName [Unresolved reference native]
```

Comment: Please add: Kotlin version, which source set(s) you're including that annotation (common code or some Windows-specific code), the Gradle task that's failing, and the actual error you're getting.

Comment: thanks @kevin-galligan, further info added above